# Ant build makes disk used up to 100%

Tags: java, ant

I am sorting out ways to increase speed of Ant building job.

My project contains hundreds of java classes, each Ant job of JAR building to Tomcat requires me 1 to 2 mins.

And I discovered whenever any Ant building job is being executed, the disk percentage on Windows Task Manager boost up to 100%.

I use my collegue's computer to try, we are using same version of Ant, Tomcat, and JDK on the same project, but at the meantime only 10 secs is used up for building JAR in his computer. I opened his Task Manager, discovered that the disk percentage is also boosted up, but only up to 9X%.

But in my case, it's 100%.

Is there any way to lower the disk usage during Ant building? Or is there any other way to improve the Ant build speed?

Comment: Compilation reads/writes everything from/to disk, doesn't surprise me there's a lot of IO. You sure you don't just have a machine with poor specs/settings?

Comment: Often, this is due to approaching the max physical memory on your machine. As you approach the max, the OS gets starved and the memory starts getting paged, your process paused to allow another process to run, your memory written to disk, then loaded again to give your process execution time..then back to disk, and over an over. This causes your disk utilization to be high. Check the used memory on your computer. If necessary, limit the amount of memory used by Ant by setting the JVM memory parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not a satisfying answer, but it's most likely that ant hits the specs of your machine. If it also feels slow to you as a user, it means your machine specs are simply underpowered for your development tasks.

I do not know if cached I/O also appears as I/O in the windows task manager, but in any case it means that your I/O is slower than ant itself (CPU). Are you still using rotational storage? Maybe replace it with an SSD.

Also check if you're running out of RAM. If you run out of RAM, I/O increases significantly due to page swapping. If you run out of RAM, simply increase your RAM. For a developer machine, I'd say 2 GiB is minimum on Linux/Arm, 4 GiB on Linux/i386, 8 GiB on Linux/x64 or Mac OS X and 16 GiB on Windows. Note that this is of course only a subjective rule of thumb guideline, and depending on what you do, less might be sufficient or more might be required.